# Is it possible to use SonarLint in a Gradle multi-project from within IntelliJ?

Tags: intellij-idea, sonarlint-intellij

I have a Gradle multi-project which looks like this:

Project A

- Subproject #1
- Subproject #2
- Subproject #3

For each sub project there is a corresponding SonarQube project on the central server.

Using SonarLint 2.2 for IntelliJ 2016.1.2 I can use connected mode against our central SonarQube 5.1.8 server. In the SonarLint Project Settings I need to supply the project binding. This is a problem; I can only analyze one subproject at the same time. Apparently the project binding is used for the entire multi-project.

I found this issue on the SonarLint JIRA; https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SLI-91. It seems as if a multi-project isn't supported in version 2.2, but is in 2.3.

Is there someone who got this set-up running?